# Write like and not like dynamically in plpgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, sql-like

SQL1:

```
select regno from student where regno **like 'ABCD%'**
```

This is running successfully. But how can I write **like 'ABCD%'** dynamically?
For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_regno(refcursor, character varying)
RETURNS refcursor AS
$BODY$
begin
select regno from student where regno $1
return $1;
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Now I want to pass **$1** as **like 'ABCD%'** i.e.:

```
select check_regno(f1, "like 'ABCD%'")
```

This will give `error at $1`:

Please suggest how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

As @Igor mentioned, this is error prone. I would go one step further: **Don't do it**. You invite SQL injection. Consider this [related answer on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718).

In fact, I don't see anything in your question warranting dynamic SQL at all. Use a plain SQL function and pass a plain string value instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_regno(_like bool, _filter text)
  RETURNS SETOF text AS
$func$
SELECT regno FROM student
WHERE  CASE WHEN $1 THEN regno ~~ $2 ELSE regno !~~ $2 END
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

`~~` and `!~~` being Postgres operators for `LIKE` and `NOT LIKE` (you can use either).

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM check_regno(TRUE, 'ABCD%');
SELECT * FROM check_regno(FALSE, 'DEFG%');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_regno(p_filter varchar)
RETURNS SETOF student.regno%TYPE AS
$BODY$
begin
  return query execute 'select regno from student where regno'||p_filter;
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;

SELECT * FROM check_regno('like ''ABCD%''');
```

But this type of dynamic SQL is error prone and can allow SQL injections.